# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord query to find single lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

ModelA has_many ModelB, and I want to find all of ModelA that have only one ModelB. I came with

```
ModelB.select('modela_id').group('modela_id').count
```

to get the number of occurence of each one, but then is there a nice Ruby way to get the list of modela_id where the count is 1? or even a better way from the beginning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [having clause](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having)

```
ModelB.select('modela_id').group('modela_id').having('count(modela_id) = ?', 1)
```